# How to verify if user is logged in via CAS

Tags: php, cas

What would be the proper way of verifying if a user is currently logged in via CAS?

At the top of every web page I have this code:

```
phpCAS::isAuthenticated();
```

but it gives me this error:

> phpCAS::isAuthenticated(): this method should not be called before
>   phpCAS::client() or phpCAS::proxy()

But if I added the call to phpCAS::client() like so:

```
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, SSO_HOSTNAME, intval(SSO_PORT), SSO_URI, false);
phpCAS::isAuthenticated();
```

I get a different error:

> phpCAS::client(): phpCAS::client() has already been called

Please note that I am able to log a user in and out via.  I simply need to verify if the user is logged in as he goes through the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpCAS sets a global variable when the client is created.  So, phpCAS::client() should be called from a globally included file - that way any calls to phpCAS::isAuthenticated() is valid.

to avoid the client from being created more than once, simply check if the global variable ( $PHPCLIENT ) is set.